# Call a function of Woocommerce plugin from my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am new to wordpress, trying to develop a **wordpress plugin** where I need to call a woocommerce method `add_to_cart` from the class `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php`. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: require_once doesn't work?
Inlucde the php file and use the class you need.
Only an idea, I am not a woocommerce developer :)
Nice weekend.

Comment: It worked for me. But had to include require many files. Just want to follow the best practices. Anyways, thankyou :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WooCommerce declares a handy globlal `WC()` that you can use inside your plugin to call its functions.

Add the following code to your plugin

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product', 'woo_foo');

function woo_foo() {        
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 254, 1 ); //ensure to change 254 with product ID on your system.               
}
```

Above code will automatically add a product to the cart when you visit the single product page. Here's a list of [hooks & filters](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) offered by WooCommerce that you can hook into.